# How to turn char array to int?

Tags: java, android

My personal problem is this, I have an array of size 32 that never comes all the fields filled. I want to convert this array to int in java.

Ex: ArrayChar = [1, .......] The first position is prenchida and the rest empty.

I tried:

`int value = Integer.parseInt (new String (buffer));`

The one exception

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1 ......"`

I would like an option that was not a loop...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: you want to convert it to int array or what?, and what does `buffer` contain?

Comment: have you verified that your string is only as long as your desired number has digits? maybe the chars get converted to spaces or something, then you would have to use String.trim()

Comment: to an integer. Ex: ArrayChar = [1,2, .......] valeu =12; "......." = empty

Comment: do you mean empty like "..."="" or is it empty like "..." contains only spaces?

Comment: not only the first filled in the rest position is empty

Comment: What's wrong about the loop?

Comment: this application very slow, with loop will become even more

Comment: There isn't anything faster. Besides, your array contains 32 elements. If your application is slow, look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, my whole problem is the technology that I am forced to use

Comment: OK. But the situation is still the same. If you are trying to find a first non-zero element and convert its value to int, as I showed in my answer, then loop is the best thing you can get. Calling for example some API method wouldn't change anything as it'd have to process the same operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] mCharArray = { '1', '2', '3','1','2' };
    int[] mIntArray = new int[mCharArray.length];
    for(int i=0;i<mCharArray.length;i++){
        mIntArray[i]=Integer.valueOf(Character.toString(mCharArray[i]));
    }
```

It should work

used this to print the int array

```
for (int c : mIntArray){
        System.out.print(c+" ");
    }
```

output is

```
1 2 3 1 2
```

Comment: hey Gabriele, it doesn´t work =(

Comment: You are right, i just edited and tested and now seems to work

Comment: Your code definitely works ! +1